# How to deform a curve in specific manner

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology, self-learning

I am wondering whether we can deform a path in specific ways continuously i mean if there is a closed piece wise $C^1$ smooth path which has to be deformed to another piece wise $C^1$ smooth path. Let us assume that deformation is possible and let the deformation function be $H(s,t)$. Denote $\gamma_t{(s)}$=$H(s,t)$. So does there exist  $H(s,t)$ such that all paths are piece wise $C^1$ smooth paths.

Comment: In what space do your paths take values?

Comment: @user86418 i am referring to $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{set of countably many points\}$